# Try and Catch Block getting error while running code on Hackerrank but in netbeans it runs well

Tags: java, time, nullpointerexception, try-catch, simpledateformat

I don't understand why it throws an error, I have declared Date date = null,
whatever value initialized to null in the try block is not global and I am getting an error

```
 DateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
    DateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    Date date=null;

    try{
        date = input.parse(s);
    }catch(ParseException e){
    }
     String newDate= output.format(date);
     return newDate;
```

Error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
at Solution.timeConversion(Solution.java:23)
at Solution.main(Solution.java:34)
```

Comment: It seems like your try statement is failing, as a result, date remains null, so then output.format(date) throws an error.

Comment: Thank you, Now I got the problem. In the String, the date was given in the format 07:05:45PM(Without WhiteSpace) and I have used SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa"); Whitespace in the line.

Comment: A general advice: never ever write a catch block that just swallows an exception doing nothing - an exception tells you something you want to know, just as you experienced it here with the ParseException. Break that rule only if you really know a very good reason to do so.

Comment: Thank You for the advice. I will surely follow it in my future codes.

Comment: Thanks, @RalfKleberhoff, for pointing out the real problem here. With the parse exception being reported it would have been much easier to find the error.

Comment: Doesn’t Hackerrank accept Java 8 code (or later)? In that case I recommend you stay off the classes `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. They are badly designed and long outdated. You should much rather use `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already commented that ignoring the ParseException was the root of your problem.

I like to point out how to solve this kind of problem in similar scenarios.

Problem: You are forced to handle a checked exception like **ParseException**. Just wrap it like this and you will not loose any information:

```
try {
    date = input.parse(s);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("put even more useful context infos for debugging here...", e);
}
```